# How to use MongoDB operators in Strongloop

Tags: mongodb, operators, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to use `$inc` for update an attribute of a Model (user), but I find two problems. I can't find if the parameter `allowExtendedOperators:true`, and I don't know if this is write correctly:

**common/user.js**

```
user.updateAttribute('coins',{ '$inc': {coins: -1} }, function(err,...);
```

**common/user.json**

```
"name": "user",
"base": "User",
"strict": true,
"idInjection": true,
"options": {
   "validateUpsert": true
}, 
...  
"settings": {
    "mongodb": {
      "allowExtendedOperators": true
    }
  },
```

I try this but nothing happen...

**server/datasource.development.js**

```
"MongoDB": {
    "host": "...",
    "port": "..."
    "database": "...",
    "name": "MongoDB",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "allowExtendedOperators": true
  }
```

I was looking for on the [documentation StrongLoop](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/MongoDB+connector?src=search&src=search#MongoDBconnector-UsingMongoDBoperatorsinupdateoperations) and the only example is to make a updateAll and says:

> There are two ways to enable the allowExtendedOperators flag: in the
>   model definition JSON file and as an option passed to the update
>   method.

But nothing works to me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the method as follows:

```
user.updateAttributes({"$inc": {coins: -1}}, callback);
```

although the callback will always return the old instance before decrementing.

Comment: wow, this works. I remove the {"allowExtendedOperators": true} from the user.json, in datasource file is required... thanks any way.